# entwine build produces a strange value for bounds in ept.json

Tags: epsg, las, pdal, laz

I am relatively new to entwine.

In our project, we have a requirement to build entwine from Laz dataset in EPSG:4326.
I understand it might sound weird that we have this dataset in geographic coordinate but it is the requirement..

However, I found whenever I try to build entwine with EPSG:4326, it produces very strange bounds in ept.json .. for instance, if I execute

```
docker run -it -v `pwd`:/entwine connormanning/entwine build -i https://data.entwine.io/red-rocks.laz -o /entwine/red-rocks-4326 -r EPSG:26913 EPSG:4326
```

this generates

```
  "bounds": [
    -199,
    -54,
    1843,
    -11,
    134,
    2031
  ],
```

which does not seem to be correct at all.

I tried to preconvert the laz data with PDAL cause `-r` option is for reprojection and not for transformation to geographic coordinates.

```
pdal translate \
  red-rocks.laz \
  red-rocks-4326.laz \
  reprojection --filters.reprojection.out_srs="EPSG:4326" \
  --writers.las.scale_x=0.0000001 \
  --writers.las.scale_y=0.0000001 \
  --writers.las.offset_x="auto" \
  --writers.las.offset_y="auto"
```

Having this output as an input for `entwine build` also generates exact the same bounds described above.

Could somebody give me some insight what I might be doing wrong here?